# How to use onhashchange with dynamic items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url, hashchange

So, I have two select boxes on a webpage, but in different anchors (one on the page, the other in an iframe) and I'm trying to get the code to detect which anchor it's in, and then relay the selected value in that box to a link. Here's my code:

```
function locationHashChanged() {
    if (location.hash === "#player") {
        function setText(text) {
            var selectVal = text;
            var url = $('twitter').attr("href");
            url = 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?button_hashtag=stream&text=Just enjoying ' + selectVal + ' on';
            $('#twitter').attr("href", url);
        }
    }

    if (location.hash === "#embeds") {
        $(function () {
            var $twitter = $('twitter');
            $('#iframe').on('load', function () {
                $(this).contents().find('#cds').change(function () {
                    var selectVal = $(this).val() || 'nothing much';
                    url = 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?button_hashtag=stream&text=Just enjoying ' + selectVal + ' on';
                     $('#twitter').attr("href", url);
                }).change();
            });
        });
    }
}
```

I know this is probably not right, or anywhere near right, but am I on the right track? I'm honestly a complete noob when it comes to javascript. Thanks in advance

Comment: "which anchor it's in" = huh?

Comment: please tell me your code isn't *really* indented like this :-)

Comment: @cbuckley no, it's much cleaner, just the way it got formatted here

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what exactly your function looks like, it's not executed on hash change right now.

You use jQuery, so you can listen for hash change like this:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
   // your locationHashChanged() function goes here
});
```

With this, every time the hash changes your function will be executed. The very base of your code is alright:

```
if (location.hash === "#player") {
    // this is executed if hash changed to #player
}

if (location.hash === "#embeds") {       
    // this is executed if hash changed to #embeds
}
```

Although, inside your `if` blocks you declare functions (which doesn't make much sense here).

Also note that if the iframe is not from your domain, you won't be able to get any data from it. If that's the case, read more about [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).